# removing file upload option in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I am new to javascript and am modifying a javascript code which has draws dynamic text on image and user can upload it.

The image will be fixed, user can't upload his own image.

Whatever I do, I am not able to remove the "choose image to upload" option from this code. Can anyone please help me with this?

My code is below:

```js
var text_title = "Heading";
var text_title1 = "Heading";
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

window.addEventListener('load', DrawPlaceholder)

function DrawPlaceholder() {
  img.onload = function() {
    DrawOverlay(img);
    DrawText();
    DynamicText(img)
  };
  img.src = 'uploads/<?php echo $image["image"] ?>';

}

function DrawOverlay(img) {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(230, 14, 14, 0)';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function DrawText() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.font = "50px 'Montserrat'";
  ctx.fillText(text_title, 50, 50);
  ctx.fillText(text_title1, 150, 250);
}

function DynamicText(img) {
  document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    DrawOverlay(img);
    DrawText();
    text_title = this.value;
    ctx.fillText(text_title, 50, 50);
  });

  document.getElementById('name1').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    DrawOverlay(img);
    DrawText();
    text_title1 = this.value;
    ctx.fillText(text_title1, 150, 250);
  });


}

function handleImage(e) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var img = "";
  var src = "";
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
    img.src = event.target.result;
    src = event.target.result;
    canvas.classList.add("show");
    DrawOverlay(img);
    DrawText();
    DynamicText(img);
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

}

function convertToImage() {
  window.open(canvas.toDataURL('png'));
}
document.getElementById('download').onclick = function download() {
  convertToImage();
}
```

```html
<input class="controls__input" type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
<label class="controls__label" for="name">First, choose an image.</label>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you need to do, remove the code to upload or make it work so it can upload. Also you have an error in the code that shows in the console - you have some PHP there that does not belong - I changed the quotes so it does not give immediate error but there are more errors then

Comment: You are missing the element that is used here: `var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');`

Comment: You are also missing `name1`

Comment: @mplungjan i want to remove the browse file option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```js
var text_title = "Heading";

var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
// img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

window.addEventListener('load', DrawPlaceholder)

function DrawPlaceholder() {
  img.onload = function() {
    DrawOverlay(img);
    DrawText(text_title);
    DynamicText(img)
  };
  img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/500x500';

}

function DrawOverlay(img) {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(230, 14, 14, 0)';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function DrawText(text) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.font = "50px 'Montserrat'";
  ctx.fillText(text, 50, 50);
}

function DynamicText(img) {
  document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    DrawOverlay(img);
    text_title = this.value;
    DrawText(text_title);
  });
}
```

```css
canvas {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" value="John" /><br/>
<canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
```